# Bold TOP Largest 50% Values in Column M

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Highlight_Top50()

    Dim CheckRange As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)

    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("M1").Sort Key1:=Range("M2"), _
      Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

With CheckRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=(SUM($M$2:M3))>=(0.5*SUM(M:M))"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Task 1: Sort data in Column M from largest to smallest (DONE!)

Task 2: Bold the top largest 50% of the summed values in Column M.

For example, 
A set of data consists of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in Column M.

1. Had them sorted from largest to smallest: 10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
2. =(SUM($M$2:M3)) To calculate the cumulative sum of the largest to smallest number
3. (0.5*SUM(M:M)) To calculate half of the summed values = 0.5*(10+9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1) = 27.5
4. Bold the range of data from largest to smallest where the cumulative sum of these range of data is greater than or equal to half of the summed values (calculated in 3.)
5. Say the cumulative sum of 10+9+8+7 = 34 is greater than 27.5, I only want these range of cells containing 10, 9, 8, 7 to be bolded.

My code ran well, however, I don't know why the values at the bottom 50% of the summed values get bolded instead of the top largest 50% of the summed values.

Kindly need help.

Comment: Is this the 4th time today you have asked this?

Comment: Yes sir, I'm getting so close to the outcome I want. Just one more clarification in order for me to close the case. Apologies for any disturbance caused.

Comment: Just invert the condition and check i.e. `Formula1:="=(SUM($M$2:M2))<=(0.5*SUM(M:M))"`.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Thanks! It works! However, 1 more problem emerged, cell containing 7 is not bolded, not align with the formula

Comment: Try this condition `=(SUM($M$2:M2)-0.99*M2)<=0.5*SUM(M:M)` and let me know how it works for you.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Now it works flawlessly!! Thanks a bunch! Could you enlighten me on 1) Why the greater than operator `>=` has to be changed to less than operator `<=` ? Supposedly the formula should work in a way that it picks the TOP 50% largest value, which means values >= the 50% summed values.

Comment: 2) `-0.99*M2)` How does this work?

Comment: I have provided explanation below which should help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach required in this particular case is

`=(SUM($M$2:M2)-0.99*M2)<=0.5*SUM(M:M)`

The logic is fairly simple.

- As long as the SUM is not exceeding the half the grand-total, each constituent number needs to be highlighted. So in OP's example it will mean 10, 9 (10+9), 8 (10+9+8) and 7 (10+9+8+7) all need to be highlighted. Highlighting shall stop at 7 where total is 34.
- Highlighting SUM less than `0.5*Grand Total` is fairly straightforward and can be achieved by `=(SUM($M$2:M2))<=(0.5*SUM(M:M))`.
- However, this formula fails to catch 7 (OP's requirement) as at this point the total starts exceeding 27.5 (excluding 7 it becomes 27 and including 7 it becomes 34). The crux is to include the number where SUM crosses halfway point i.e. 7!
- So the easy way to check if the SUM is crossing the halfway point at a number is to check SUM at penultimate number`=(SUM($M$2:M2)-M2)<=0.5*SUM(M:M)` which technically means it checks the SUM up to penultimate cell i.e. 10 (10-10), 9(10+9-9), 8(10+9+8-8),7(10+9+8+7-7) and thereby stops at the exceeding point which is 6 (10+9+8+7+6-6).
- This logic by itself will work fine if all numbers were distinct but it will fail if data populated is `(20,20,20,20,20,20)` which will incorrectly highlight 4 `20` of the populated data so to counter this we just exceed the SUM by multiplying by 0.99 which will add 1% of the last number.

This is pure mathematical logic and has got nothing to do with Excel per se. Hope this explanation helps!

Answer (score 0):

All Credits go to shrivallabha.redij!

```
Sub Highlight_Top50_AND_500K()

    Dim CheckRange As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set CheckRange = .Range("M2:M" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)

    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("M1").Sort Key1:=Range("M2"), _
      Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes, _
      OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
      Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

With CheckRange
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreaterEqual, formula1:="500000"
    With .FormatConditions(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .StopIfTrue = False
    End With
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, formula1:="=(SUM($M$2:M2)-0.99*M2)<=0.5*SUM(M:M)"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1)
         .Font.Bold = True
         .StopIfTrue = False
    End With

End With

End Sub
```